# VB.NET - Unable to connect to Named Instance on Networked Server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, connection-string

Hopefully i am just having a brain freeze, however in my VB.NET project i am unable to get a connection to the Named Instance on the networked Server from my workstation.

I am able to connect to this instance via SSMS and create ODBC Links with no issue from my workstation. If i publish the solution and run it on the Server itself is works fine, therefore the connection string is fine. I am able to connect to the default instance on the server no issue (this is used within the same solution).

Just to confirm this is the code for the connection string::

```
Public varLSConn As String = "Data Source=" & varLSServer & ";Initial Catalog=" & varLSDatabase & ";User Id=" & varLSUser & ";Password=" & varLSPassword & ";"
```

Is there a setting within the Instance i need to allow so my VB program can gain access?

Many Thanks in advance
Martin

Comment: What kind of server are you running? For tsql, make sure that your server accepts both SQL Server authentication, and that you have a working user/pass configured.

Comment: Have you enabled Named Pipes and TCP/IP on your SQL Server?
What error message do you get?

Comment: Would be helpful to see an actual error message.

Comment: I am using SQL 2016, Named Pipers and TCP/IP are both enabled, unfortunately it just gives a generic Timeout error "Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to the completion of the operation or the server is not responding" the timeout happens during the .open(). I am using the same credentials used for SSMS and ODBC links which is SQL Auth.

Comment: Well apparently it was the Server FW, however i still don't understand how it was only blocking access to the Named Instance and not the Default one. Anyways added an exception and it seems to be working fine now. Thanks for your help.